# How to write logs in a diff file for multiples instances in mfp

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, worklight-server

I have multiple instances of MFP running, but my problem is that all the instances are writing logs to a single log file. How can I write logs to diff location for diff instances?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by "multiple instances of MFP" you are referring to multiple MFP runtimes deployed on the same JVM,it is normal to see all logging appearing in the same log - SystemOut.log for WAS , messages.log for WebSphere Liberty etc.

This is because MFP is a layer that is deployed on top of the Application server and all logging from MFP is directed to the standard logging of the JVM. As such, if you deploy multiple runtime wars on the same JVM, it is normal to expect all logging from all the runtimes appear in the same log. This is not different from different EAR/WARs deployed on the same Application server, logging into the same log file.

If you wish to have different logs for different runtimes, deploy them in different JVM instances.